# convert powerpoint and keynote file to set of images

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, powerpoint

Is there a way in C or Objective-C to convert presentation files (.ppt/.key) into a set of images?

many thanks!

Comment: I searched the SO for related topics, otherwise I won't post this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt. ppt file is the fact XML style document. So if you want to parse it you have to write a XML parser who puts element in the exact position... So in fact you have to create your own powerpoint.

But, you might (both PowerPoint and Keynote) consider to export presentation to pdf, and then this will be a lot simpler.

Comment: thanks, parsing XML and re-represent them seems a lot work. I may consider the later option.

Answer (score 1):

For PowerPoint, you can get each slide, present it through UIWebView and capture the image from view
[IOS library to convert powerpoint presentations into images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15971969/ios-library-to-convert-powerpoint-presentations-into-images/18129059#18129059)

Answer (score 0):

It would be more helpful to know why you want to do this, but on mac, it's possible to do this kind of thing with [javascript](http://www.jaimerios.com/?p=171)  and it's possible to call javascript from within [cocoa](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptingBridgeConcepts/Introduction/Introduction.html)

I doubt you'll have any luck if you want to do it in iOS.

Comment: thanks, I read the blog, the js code uses MS software to do the job. So it's not possible on iOS. I may consider using cloud service instead.

Answer (score 0):

PowerPoint for Mac offers a **Save as Pictures** open in the File menu that sounds like what you are looking for.